# Why jQuery dont see events in my TS constructor class

Tags: javascript, jquery, typescript

I have a TS script, this is a combinatorics for my study theme.

I am including jQuery to simplify DOM events handling.

In npm I installed all dependencies, build is fine - no errors.

main.ts

```
import * as $ from 'jquery';
import {Totalizator} from "./totalizator/totalizator";


$(() => {
    new Totalizator($('#totalizator'), 42, 5);
});
```

totalizator.ts

```
import * as $ from 'jquery';

const classes = {
    number: 'number'
};

const selectors = {
    number: `.${classes.number}`,
    numbersTable: '#totalizatorNumbersTable',
    chosenNumbersTable: '#totalizatorChosenNumbersTable'
};

export class Totalizator {
    private $container: JQuery;

    private readonly numbers: number;
    private readonly choices: number;

    constructor($container: JQuery, numbers: number, choices: number) {
        this.$container = $container;
        this.numbers = numbers;
        this.choices = choices;

        this.printNumbersTable();
        this.printChosenNumbersTable();

        // this is working, I can see on console, there is a jQuery object
        console.log(this.$container);

        // but this is not working
        $(this.$container).on(`${selectors.numbersTable} ${classes.number}`, 'click', (event) => {
            console.log(event);
        });
    }
}
```

When I click on the "number", there should be an event fired, why is it not?

Note: `totalizator.ts` is simplified. I am including only constructor, rest of the code is not important, only HTML printing.

Basic jQuery will look like this, but in my TS it is not working, whatever I write:

```
$('#totalizator').on('#totalizatorNumbersTable .number', 'click', (event) => {
    console.log(event);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You use `classes.number` in your template string interpolation, which value is `"number"`, whereas you should have used instead your variable `selectors.number`, which adds the dot (`.`) to convert it as a CSS class selector (`.${classes.number}`)

---

Next, the syntax for jQuery [`.on`](https://api.jquery.com/on/) method is `.on( events [, selector ] [, data ], handler )`, i.e. the event name first, and selector (for event delegation) next.

Therefore in your case you should have:

```
$(this.$container).on('click', `${selectors.numbersTable} ${selectors.number}`, (event) => {
  console.log(event);
});

// Equivalent to:
$('#totalizator').on('click', '#totalizatorNumbersTable .number', (event) => {
    console.log(event);
});
```

Comment: You're right, I totally messed up and didn't notice that I replaced the checked event with the selector. Apparently I was too tired already to saw this